# Яндекс.Почта подменяет ссылку из письма и прогоняет через свой сервис учёта

Tags: javascript, html, href, яндекс-почта

Яндекс Почта подменяет ссылку из письма и прогоняет через свой сервис учёта.   Как это отключить?

Это ссылка которую браузер показывает как целевая href="https://www.olx.ua/d/obyavlenie/plate-akinut-sviter-zhenskiy-QPxzc444.html"

А сюда переходит после клика.

> https://mail.yandex.ru/re.jsx?uid=09876&mid=1234892185281176125&c=LIZA&cv=27.9.0&h=a,hbKBKCTfdg2qkO_fK_PlwFQ&l=asdre43Ly93d3cub2x4LnVhL2Qvb2J5YXZsZW5pZS9wbGF0ZS10dW5pa2Etc3ZpdGVyLXpoZW5za2l5LUlETkRoUFEuaHRtbB

<sub>(ссылки я естественно подменил)</sub>

Надо полагать что Яндекс прицепил подменятор href на OnClick() и обманывает юзверя таким образом. Так же делает гугл и другие.

Кто знает как это побороть - желательно общим универсальным методом?
Попросту говоря я ищу monkey script или подсказку о том как его правильно написать - отследить подмену и убрать её. А возможно запретить подвес колбэков на событие.в общем любой спрособ хорош.

Варианты обхода:

- копировать ссылку, вставить, перейти
- Отключение JS - неудобства
- Не использовать их сайт - юзать любой почтовый клиент

Comment: Ну, Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - не использовать сайт, использовать почтовый клиент. А насчет "обманывает пользователя" - Вы же не удивляетесь, когда посылаете сылку другу по телеграмму, а в тот же момент по этой ссылке заходит телеграмм-бот и скачивает контент к себе, чтобы красиво показать превьюшку в сообщении? так что "обманывает пользователя" - это слишком сильное утверждение...

Comment: При чем тут превьюшкп

Comment: Я говорю про переход по прямой ссылке и подмену href

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится проблема при включенном адблоке.

Comment: А без адблока проявляется?

Comment: Я это обнаружил благодаря контейнерам ФФ. Он показал что переход по ссылке внутрь Яндекса и спросил хочу ли я его открыть в контейнере. А без этого глазами просто так не увидишь...